# Usage of “wash"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I came across this line in something I was reading:

> The anger and tension washed out of his body.

It feels a little iffy to me. Is the usage of ‘wash’ correct here? If it’s not, why?

Comment: Yes, the usage is correct.

Comment: It's like when something depleted either your strength or vitality.

Comment: In anger, Adrenalin floods the blood stream. The same blood-flow does literally wash the adrenalin / adrenaline/ epinephrin away. So,it is a good metaphor for ebbing anger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wash?s=t

**wash out** (meaning No. 52) - a bit murky, but what they mean to say is "to get out through washing"